# how to remove last newline character from a file in TCL

Tags: tcl

i need a code to remove only a last newline character from a file in TCL.
suppose a file

```
aaa 11
bbb 12
cc 14
newline character
```

now how to remove that newline character from a file in TCl
please help me in this!

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific part of the problem you don't understand, or are you asking us to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

[Seeking](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M38) and [truncating](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M43) are your friend. (Requires Tcl 8.5 or later.)

```
set f [open "theFile.txt" r+]

# Skip to where last newline should be; use -2 on Windows (because of CRLF)
chan seek $f -1 end
# Save the offset for later
set offset [chan tell $f]
# Only truncate if we're really sure we've got a final newline
if {[chan read $f] eq "\n"} {
    # Do the truncation!
    chan truncate $f $offset
}

close $f
```

For removing data from *anywhere* other than the end of the file, it's easiest to rewrite the file (either by loading the data all into memory or by streaming and transforming to a new file that you move back over, the latter being harder but necessary with large files). Truncation can only work at the end.

Comment: I need it in 8.4 version of tcl... can u plz help me in this plz